# Using str_replace() to replace two types of filenames

Tags: php, str-replace

I know I can convert the filename from `.xlsx` to `.csv` like this:

```
$pFileName = "hello.xlsx"
str_replace(".xlsx", ".csv", $pFileName);
```

... and convert `.xls` to `.csv` like this:

```
$pFileName = "hello.xls"
str_replace(".xls", ".csv", $pFileName);
```

My question is, how can I make a single function that converts my filename to `.csv` if its `.xlsx` or `.xls`? This means, "change the file name to .csv if it's .xls or xlsx in one single (if it's possible) `str_replace`.

I tried with a double `str_replace` with no luck:

```
str_replace(str_replace(".xlsx", ".csv", $pFileName), ".csv", $pFileName)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an array and replace it with some values, See my answer.

Comment: `str_replace(['.xls', '.xlsx'], '.csv', $string);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple:

```
str_replace(array(".xlsx", ".xls"), ".csv", $pfilename);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an array to [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace([".xlsx", ".xls"], ".csv", $pFileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

I comment to use array like:

```
$pfilename = "hello.xlsx";

$arr = array(".xlsx", ".xls");
echo str_replace($arr, ".csv", $pfilename); // hello.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `preg_replace`

```
$pFileName = "hello.xls";
echo $filename = preg_replace('"\.(xls|xlsx)$"', '.csv', $pFileName);
```